# Did compositing in Cycles, went to eevee for the background, went back to cycles... and all my compositing had been deleted

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine, compositing-nodes, world

How do I solve that? I had a beautiful planet and now the planet is all pink and plain, not really what I want. Everything that was in the compositing editor is not there anymore. [image: Now]  [image: Before]

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved it, I actually confounded the compositor tab with the shading tab. The pink color was because I had previously deleted the file of the surface of the planet. I put a newer version of the file I did on Photoshop inside the "Image texture" block in the shading tab and tadaa... the planet is no longer pink.